# Changing iPhone X status bar style color to white

Tags: ios, swift

I need to change the status bar content color to white in my iPhone project.

I have done this by

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
```

[image]

This changes the color but there is one problem. On iPhone X the time on the top left is getting truncated. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Changing color won't cause time to be truncated. It's more likely an autolayout issue.

Comment: But it works fine with dark color so might be an ios issue

Answer (score 0):

Usually these types of issues arise because of date time format. Can you please check your settings app, in particular General->International and General->Date & Time and by changing those settings and see the behavior.

Besides these its necessary to take a look of your code, if you have any customization for status bar except color.

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Santosh Jayapal can you try this In `appDelegate.swift` , the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function, add:

`UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent`

Comment: Hi Mitesh this seems to be an older solution which doesnt work in newer ios versions.

Comment: Hi @SantoshJayapal i use this code in my iOS app in my project two different different colour status bar like :- view1 in Default bar and view 2 in light status bar and its work perfectly. Swift 4.2 and iOS 12.3

Comment: Oh okay then i will recheck that thanks a lot Mitesh :)